# How to bookmark a Chrome Link-to-text-fragment URL?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Chrome's Link-to-text-fragment extension produces a link that can be shared with others.  However, the only way to create a *Chrome bookmark* of it for one's own use seems convoluted ( 1. create a bookmark for the original page, 2. Perform the link-to-text-fragment URL,  3. Relocate the original bookmark, and paste the new URL into it).  Is there a faster, easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Copy highlight to link.
2. Open a new tab and paste link.
3. Click on "Bookmark this tab" **WITHOUT** clicking or scrolling on anything on the page.

Clicking or scrolling will clear the fragment from the address bar.